# Sql Query to Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have written an sql qyery like

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
  [tlotWeight]
  ,[TEU]
  ,[SeaAirFlag]
  ,CASE 
  WHEN [SeaAirFlag]='SEA' OR [SeaAirFlag]='Sea' 
  then [TEU]  
  else [tlotWeight] end as Volume
FROM [LogisticsBI].[dbo].[GoldenVolume]
```

I want it to convert it to linq c# query,I have tried something like this

```
(from t in db.GoldenVolumes
 select new { Volume=(t.SeaAirFlag=="SEA"|| t.SeaAirFlag=="Sea")?t.TEU: t.tlotWeight)}
 ).Take(10000).Distinct()
```

but its showing some syntax error in linqpad 
Please help me to correct way in linq to write this query

Comment: "*but its showing some syntax error*" - what exactly error you're getting? There are no mind-readers here....

Comment: error is : Syntax error, ',' expected

) expected

Comment: Use LINQPad to Help ease into LINQ syntax https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad

Comment: `(from t in db.GoldenVolumes select new { Volume = (t.SeaAirFlag=="SEA"|| t.SeaAirFlag=="Sea") ? t.TEU : t.tlotWeight }).Take(10000).Distinct();`

Comment: I have use LINQPad in that only it is showing syntax error                  Syntax error, ',' expected ) expected

Comment: Small typos don't really belong on SO. You should have been able to find the mistake if you spent a few minutes yourself.

Comment: looks like you got confused with all those brackets around

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see problem with brackets here (opened one time and closed two times):

```
select new { Volume = (t.SeaAirFlag=="SEA" || t.SeaAirFlag=="Sea") ? t.TEU : t.tlotWeight)}
```

It looks like this should be either

```
select new { Volume = ((t.SeaAirFlag=="SEA" || t.SeaAirFlag=="Sea") ? t.TEU: t.tlotWeight)}
```

or (it's up to you)

```
select new { Volume = (t.SeaAirFlag=="SEA" || t.SeaAirFlag=="Sea") ? t.TEU: t.tlotWeight }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straightforward you have misarranged your round brackets.

**t.tlotWeight)})** is wrong instead it should be **t.tlotWeight})**

Its better to split them to next lines for more clearity.

```
    var res = (from t in db.GoldenVolumes
                   select new
                   {
                       Volume = (t.SeaAirFlag.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("SEA")) ?
                           t.TEU  : t.tlotWeight
                   })

                   .Take(10000)
                   .Distinct();
```